# multi-purpose of a handler for setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, timeout, handle

I know that if I assign a setTimeout to a handler (a variable) I later have the option of unsetting it.

But I wonder, if I do this

```
    this.emptyScreenTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        self.getAllModulesAjax(null,true);
    },5*60*1000);
```

will that automatically prevent me from getting multiple instances of this timeout?

If this code is run now, and then before the timeout has happened, this code is run again, will that que a second event or will the first one be removed from the que (unset) and replaced with a new one to run in (5*60*1000) ms since they have the same handle?

Comment: no, the new handle will replace the old in that property, but if you duped the old it will still work with clearTimeout, and both calls will fire as scheduled

Comment: Unless you call `clearTimeout`, the callback will still run.  That's the only way to stop a timeout.  If you re-run this code, it will run a 2nd timeout and overwrite the variable with the 2nd handler.